# Example How to represent table from RDBMS to HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, nosql

I read few articles and videos on YouTube about HBase. 
I understood that HBase is hadoop database. And it has different architecture (like column group etc.) compared to RDBMs.
But I am still not clear how a RDBMs table will be represented in HBase?

Let me know if there is any suitable tutorial available.

e.g. If I have employee table with column as id, first_name, last_name, departement_id and salary.
And Department table with departement_id, dept_name as columns.

If I want to represent it in HBase how will it be defined ? Can someone please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic concepts like "table in HBase can be visualized as Map of Map" and how timestamp is used was clarified by
http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Understanding_Hbase_and_BigTable

Then I found explanation in this PDF very useful
http://0b4af6cdc2f0c5998459-c0245c5c937c5dedcca3f1764ecc9b2f.r43.cf2.rackcdn.com/9353-login1210_khurana.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [link](https://sunilmistri.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/hbase-schema-design/). The internal architecture is different from the RDBMS. You have rows, column families, column qualifiers. Internally all the details are stored as key:value pairs. More videos with good information [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/resources/library/hbasecon/video-hbasecon-2012-hbasecon-2012.html). The question asked seems like you might be thinking to join those two tables. This [post](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_joins) might give info regarding that aspect. There is also a Tall vs wide table design aspect here

HBase: The Definitive Guide book's chapter 9 talks about Tall-Narrow vs Flat-wide tables.
(http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449396107/advanced.html)

which might help you in your decision. In a nut shell, your design would be based on which parameters you would like to retrieve data. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

you can use sqoop to import and export tables from hbase to RDBMS and vice versa

Comment: It is not about import-export commands; question is more about concept/theory

Comment: you're talking about Hbase mapping ! it's up to you how you want to mapp data into fields for your example you can create a Hbase table with 2 Column families  ; the first one for employee with id, first_name, last_name, departement_id and salary as column qualifiers and the second column family for  Department with departement_id, dept_name as  column qualifiers